# Android API 19+: sometimes no type in DocumentsContract.getDocumentId from image and it cannot be found with id

Tags: android, filepath, mediastore

We're trying to load images with a pick intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true); 
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, R.integer.ACT_SELECT_IMAGE);
```

in onActivityResult we get the uri for every image with:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {     
    if (requestCode == R.integer.ACT_SELECT_IMAGE)
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            try {                   
                if(data.getClipData() != null) {
                    int count = data.getClipData().getItemCount();
                    int currentItem = 0;
                    while(currentItem < count) {
                        try {
                            Uri imageUri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(currentItem).getUri();
                            [...]
                        } catch (Exception e){[...]}
                        currentItem = currentItem + 1;
                    }
                } else if(data.getData() != null) {
                    Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                    [...]
                }
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                [...]
            }
        }
     [...]
    }
```

The problem lies with Android Device API 19+:

In most cases the *wholeID* (edit: was *imageUri*) looks like "image:12345" but sometimes we get ids with only the "12345" without the type part.
It even happens that when we select multiple images at once that some come with type and some without...
If an image comes without type then it will always be without type. Everytime you select this specific picture the type part will be missing and the code below will return a wrong path ...

edit for blackapps:
uri.toString() with type looks like **content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A12345**

uri.toString() without type looks like **content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/12345**

Tested on a Samsung Galaxy S9 with Android 10.

we get the path to the images with:

```
public String getRealPathFromURI_API19(Uri uri) {
    String filePath = "";
    String wholeID = android.provider.DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
    
    String id = null;
    String[] column = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Uri contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    if (wholeID.contains(":")) {
        id = wholeID.split(":")[1];
    } else {
        id = wholeID;           
    }
    
    String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, column, sel,
            new String[]{id}, null);

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return filePath;
}
```

But if the "image:" part is missing in the ID then filePath does not match the image that was picked in the pick intent but some completely different image.

I think that the returned id is not an id from **MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI**, even if we specifically queried it with the pick intent.

Does someone know which provider we could try?
I tried **MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI** but that didn't work either...

Comment: You use two actions in your intent. Confusing. Go for one. Please adapr your code also here.

Comment: `In most cases the imageUri looks like "images:12345"` No. That is only a part of the uri. Have a look at data.getData().toString() instead.

Comment: `we get the path to the images with:`. Wrong. Bad. One does not try to convert a nice uri to a path as one can use the uri directly.

Comment: you're right, imageUri does not look like "images:12345". it's wholeID that looks like "images:12345". I'll correct the question.

Comment: You have not changed what you should change. You should post full uries to begin with. The values of uri.toString().

Comment: @blackapps: I removed `intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);` and now it's working. Write your comment as answer and i'll accept it.